# No WiFi with Mac mini M2

Tags: keyboard, wifi, mouse, mac-mini

New Mac mini M2. The WiFi will not be recognized though all other devices work fine. Our Internet provider checked, and the signal strength is fine.

Apple blames the Internet provider. Clearly it’s the Mac mini. Now, neither the Magic Keyboard nor mouse work.

How can I fix these wireless issues?

Comment: Start by turning the mini on its side (I know how silly this sounds) or make sure it’s “all by itself in the open.”  In other words, don’t put a monitor or anything on top or around it.  The fact that you’re having issues with both WiFi and BT signals a problem with either the antenna or the AirPort card.